# Java reading number of lines in two files while using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, file, count

I posted yesterday about this but my code was messy. What I'm looking to do is count the number of lines of two separate files and print the line number in a separate thread for each file.
This is what i have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fileReader implements Runnable
{    
    static int count = 0;
    static int count1 = 0;

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
        Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("filetest1.txt"));
        Scanner file2 = new Scanner(new File("filetest2.txt"));

        while (file1.hasNextLine()) 
        {
              count++;
              file1.nextLine();
        }

        while (file2.hasNextLine()) 
        {
              count1++;
              file2.nextLine();
        }
     }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            count = -1;
            count1 = -1;
        }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            (new Thread(new fileReader())).start();
            System.out.println("File one has " + count + " lines");
            System.out.println("File two has " + count1 + " lines");

    }

}
```

The problem is that it does not work. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: do you want to count one file in each thread?  right now, you're using one thread to count the lines in 2 files.  That's not really multithreading at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the thread to finish its job.
You print your resault too early.
thr.join() blocks your program until thr finishes.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Thread thr = new Thread(new fileReader());

            thr.start();
            thr.join();

            System.out.println("File one has " + count + " lines");
            System.out.println("File two has " + count1 + " lines");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(fileReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please remove `Poligon`, and redundant code, just leave `thr.start()` and `thr.join()` part as the answer, otherwise it is confusing

Comment: The problem that i originally had still persists, it still prints 0 lines.

Comment: are you sure you start and join the same thread? because my solution prints the correct number.

Comment: Yep, if i add a catch exception of count = -1; then it will print -1 instead. It seems that its not counting the lines in the file.

Comment: It look like it cannot find a file. Make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: add
 e.printStackTrace();
to your exception

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track using `Runnable`.  You have a couple problems right now:

1. You currently create 1 `fileReader` with 1 thread for both files, but your intent is to have a *separate* thread for each.
2. You are trying to communicate between threads using some static variables, but you're not waiting for the worker thread to be done before printing the variables.

To solve your first problem, you need to create a new `Runnable` and a new thread for each file.  (I'm going to rename your `fileReader` class to `LineCounter` to avoid confusion with the similarly named `FileReader` from the standard library).

```
class LineCounter implements Runnable {
    private final File file;

    public LineCounter(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Count lines in file.
    }
}
```

Now you can create 2 separate LineCounter objects, one to count the lines in each file.

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new LineCounter(new File("filetest1.txt")));
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new LineCounter(new File("filetest2.txt")));
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

As for your second problem, your main thread must (the one that spawned off these two other threads) needs to wait for them to complete before reading the variables holding the number of lines in each file.  You can instruct your main thread to wait for the another thread to complete by using `join()`

```
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
// Print your variables.
```

That being said, communicating between threads with static variables is dubious at best:

1. To really do this right, you'd have to either `synchronize` access to those variables, or else declare them as `volatile`.
2. When programming with threads, it's preferable to share as little state (variables) as possible with other threads.

Further, there exists the very convenient `Executor` framework which presents a nicer API for dealing with threads.  One big win is that is allows you to easily return a value from a thread, which you could use to return the number of lines read.

The big changes are:

- Your class implements `Callable<Integer>` instead of `Runnable`.  The `<Integer>` part here means you want your thread to return an Integer (i.e. the number of lines in the file)
- Instead of `void run()`, you define `Integer call()`, which returns the number of lines in the file.
- Instead of creating `Thread`s directly, you *submit* tasks to be done to an `Executor`.
- Instead of `join()`ing threads together, simply `get()` the return value of a thread from a `Future`.

Converted to Executor style, the solution is something like

```
class LineCounter implements Callable<Integer> {
    private final File file;

    public LineCounter(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public Integer call() {
        // Count number of lines in file.
        return numLines;
    }
}
```

And in your main thread:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Future<Integer> future1 = executor.submit(new LineCounter(new File("file1.txt")));
Future<Integer> future2 = executor.submit(new LineCounter(new File("file2.txt")));
Integer file1Lines = future1.get();
Integer file2Lines = future2.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class fileReader1 implements Runnable
{    
    static int count = 0;
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
        Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("filetest1.txt"));
         ............
         ............
         ............
    }
}

public class fileReader2 implements Runnable
{    
    static int count = 0;
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
        Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("filetest2.txt"));
         ............
         ............
         ............
   }
}
```

Now you can start two threads and start reading the files simultaneously:

```
Thread t1=new Thread(new fileReader1());
Thread t2=new Thread(new fileReader2());

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: or pass the file name into the constructor of the file reader class, so you don't have 2 duplicate classes.

Comment: @JohnGardner what ever i have said is a valid solution. It's not may be perfect but does job well. As the other person has not done that as well.